# running video over qt client

Tags: c++, qt, audio, ubuntu

I compiled a streaming client developed by Qt in Ubuntu 12.04. I can watch videos without audio. However, when I want to play a video containing audio, I get this message in the terminal:

```
using null output device none available
```

After research in the Internet, I figured that this is caused by Qt.

Comment: Not much to help here. Sure, the warning message comes from Qt. But the reason is probably a wrongly configured audio system. Loosely spoken: Qt does not find a sound card.

Comment: Can you point to the streaming client you are using?  The error you got is more than probably related with the configuration of your audio system on Ubuntu.